# Call a lightbox on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, mouseover

My doubt is actually pretty simple. I have an image of a V890 server and on mouseover of that image i want to call a lightbox,which shows the specs of that server.
I cant get the code to work. Also never used 'onmouseover' function before so dunno how to write the code.

I have found a useful lightbox called 'lightwondow'.

```
<a href="http://www.p51labs.com/lightwindow/blank-huge.html"class="lightwindow page-options" title="Sample Title"><strong>Monster Fixed Page</strong> - This page is just plain to big for the browser window unless you maximize a 30 inch monitor.</a>
```

I need to add a mouseover to this code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Anand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think the lightbox is usually load at the onclick event, you have to change that to be able to lauch it onmouseover.

Open the file lightbox.js an change the line:

```
anchor.onclick = function () {myLightbox.start(this); return false;}
```

with:

```
anchor.onmouseover= function () {myLightbox.start(this); return false;}
```

By the way i think you ahve to add the *rel* attribute to the anchor:

```
 rel="lightbox"
```

HTH!